# RepeatedColumnException in JPA entity for Composite\Foreign keys

Tags: exception, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a primary key on two columns in the table EmployeeCode

PRIMARY KEY (ecode,eid)

And for this I have the below in my JPA entity files (EmployeeCode.java)

```
@EmbeddedId
private EmployeeCodePK id;
```

and in EmployeeCodePK

```
@Column(name="ECODE")
private long ecode;

@Column(name="EID")
private long eid;
```

The column eid is a foreign key referencing the table Employee with a ManytoOne mapping for which I have declared the below in EmployeeCode.java

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="EID")
private Employee employee;
```

When I do this I get the below exception since I am using EID at both the places (Since it is a foreign key to another table and also part of the composite primary key)

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.skyteam.api.lounges.domain.persistence.entities.LoungeFacility column: LOUNGE_ID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:682)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:704)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:726)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:479)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
```

How can I use the same name at both places?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the @JoinColumn as below worked for me

```
@JoinColumn(name="EID", referencedColumnName = "EID",insertable = false, updatable = false)
```